# Application does not run in background, when we press window button

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, gps, location

I have a problem in Windows Phone application development.
I want to know that when we press window key, our application deactivates, but why does it not run in background?

I implemented Geolocator methods and written following text in WMAppManifest.xml file

```
<Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="Registration.xaml">
        <BackgroundExecution>
          <ExecutionType Name="LocationTracking" />
        </BackgroundExecution>
      </DefaultTask>
    </Tasks>
```

To run application in background.

But application run in background only when GPS is on in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone there is there is no possibility to run application in background, only agents are allowed, but they are being launched once per 30 minutes, but I am sure that you know that already. Although it is possible to run application under lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature. If `GeoCoordinateWatcher` is not actively tracking location, app is deactivated from background running. Look at [Running location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) page:

Conditions under which the operating system will deactivate an app running in the background:

- **The app stops actively tracking location. An app stops tracking location by removing event handlers for the PositionChanged and StatusChanged events of the Geolocator class or by calling the Stop() method of the GeoCoordinateWatcher class.**
- The app has run in the background for 4 hours without user interaction.
- Battery Saver is active.
- Device memory is low.
- **The user disables Location Services on the phone.**
- Another app begins running in the background.